# How to set UITextField text to text that we copy?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a UITextField, and I want to set the UITextField text to string that I coppied from this:

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = myVoucher.voucherCode
```

Is there anyone know how to do this? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `textField.text = UIPasteboard.general.string`?

Comment: yes and it works. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Just set it from where you stored that value.

**Copy:**

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = textField.text
```

**Paste:**

```
textField.text = UIPasteboard.general.string
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the string from UIPasteboard and check if it contains any string then set it as a textfield's text.

```
if let string = UIPasteboard.general.string {
  // use the string, for example:
   yourTextField.text = string
}else {
 //There is no text in Pasteboard
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `guard` instead

```
guard let copyString = UIPasteboard.general.string else {
    return
}

textField.text = copyString
```